# How to keep column order after df.update() + df.reset_index()

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes.

`data_df`

```
  Investor   Company Name      CUSIP Symbol
0     Hank       FaCeBoOk  30303M102       
1     Dale       Fraud Co  88160R101       
2     Bill    Netflix Inc  64110L106       
3     Kahn                 64110L106       
4    Peggy         Amazon   23135106       
5    Rusty         Costco  22160K105       
6    Bobby  BankAmericard  92826C839       
7     Minh    Placeholder  92826C839       
8   Chappy          Other  29786A106
```

and `cusips_df`:

```
         Company Name Symbol      CUSIP
0            Facebook     FB  30303M102
1               Tesla   TSLA  88160R101
2         Netflix Inc   NFLX  64110L106
3              Amazon   AMZN   23135106
4              Costco   COST  22160K105
5                Visa      V  92826C839
6        Mega-Lo Mart    MLM  543535F63
7  Strickland Propane   SPPN  453HGR001
8                Etsy   ETSY  29786A106
```

I am matching the two dataframes on `CUSIP`, and then updating the `Company Name` and `Symbol` in `data_df` with those values from `cusips_df`.

```
data_df = data_df.set_index('CUSIP')
cusips_df = cusips_df.set_index('CUSIP')
data_df.update(cusips_df)
data_df = data_df.reset_index()
print(data_df)
```

But when I do, the `CUSIP` column gets moved to position `0`, rather than stay in position `2`:

```
       CUSIP Investor Company Name Symbol
0  30303M102     Hank     Facebook     FB
1  88160R101     Dale        Tesla   TSLA
2  64110L106     Bill  Netflix Inc   NFLX
3  64110L106     Kahn  Netflix Inc   NFLX
4   23135106    Peggy       Amazon   AMZN
5  22160K105    Rusty       Costco   COST
6  92826C839    Bobby         Visa      V
7  92826C839     Minh         Visa      V
8  29786A106   Chappy         Etsy   ETSY
```

I know I can simply reorder the dataframe columns, but is there a more pythonic way of doing this so that the order of the columns in `data_df` stays the same?

Answer (score 1):

We can do

```
d=dict(zip(cusips_df.CUSIP, cusips_df.Symbol))
data_df.Symbol.update(data_df.CUSIP.map(d))
```

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'CUSIP'`

Comment: @MSD so you dataframe do not have columns CUSIP?